# How To Speed Up Item Descriptions Matching Using FuzzyWuzzy in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of item descriptions that I read from a csv column, and I am trying to look for matches on another list of item descriptions. But it is currently extremely slow as it is trying to match each item on list 1 to every item on list 2.

Here is an example of the item descriptions:

```
Item description list 1 = [BAR EVENING DREAM INTENSE DARK 3.5 OZ GHRDLLI]
Item description list 2 = [GHIARDELLI EVENING DREAM INTENSE DARK BAR 3.5 OZ 60% (60716)]
this shows the closest match.
```

A little bit of my code that uses FuzzyWuzzy extractOne token_sort_ration

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import re
from re import findall 

regex_size = '([0-9]+((\.\d+)?)+(OZ|CT|oz|ct|(\sOZ)|(\sCT)|(\soz)|(\sct)))'
regex_size_oz_check = '(?=(OZ|oz|(\sOZ)|(\soz)))'
regex_size_ct_check = '(?=(CT|ct|(\sCT)|(\sct)))'

with open('IC_ITM_CROSS_REF', 'r') as hosts:
        reader = csv.reader(hosts, delimiter='|')

        #iterate through each
        for row in reader:
            #row[2] = size, can be in OZ or CT
            list1_item_desc = row[1] + " " + row[2] + " " + row[4];

            #look for matching REPORT_UPC_CODE
            if row[7] in UPC:
                message = "UPC match" 

            #if items UPC doesn't match, check if item descriptions match or not
            else:
                #look for matching Item Desc (return the highest percentage of item desc matching)
                #more defined search on the item size
                highest = process.extractOne(list1_item_desc,list(all_other_item_desc),scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
                if highest[1] > 80:
                    #check if the size match 
                    other_item_size = list(map(lambda x: x[0], findall(regex_size, highest[0]))) 
                    other_item_size_lower = list(map(lambda x:x.replace(" ", "").lower(),other_item_size))
                    if(row[2].replace(" ", "").lower() in other_item_size_lower) or not other_item_size:
                        print("MATCH")
```

The way the code works currently is that it first tries to see if the item's UPC codes match or no. If it does not, then it will try to look at the item descriptions. For each item description on list 1, it will try to pull one item description from other_item_description list that it most closely matches.

Currently, I have about thousands of items in list1 and thousands of items in another list. So it is extremely slow, it can take a couple of hours to finish running. Is there a way to speed this up? I'm still so new to Python programming and any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to speed this up.

1. You can replace FuzzyWuzzy with [rapidfuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz) (I am the author), which does the same but is faster.
2. Right now your strings get preprocessed when calling extractOne, so they are e.g. lowercased before comparing them. For the list of choices this can be done once in front of your loop.
3. Beside this I replaced your map comnstructs with a set, which should be slightly faster, but is especially simpler to read.
4. UPC should be a set aswell, so you have the constant lookup time, while with a list it has to iterate over the whole list until it finds the item (which is slow when working with big lists like you do)

I could not test this, since I do not have access to the required data, but these changes should give you quite a big performance improvement.

```py
from rapidfuzz import process, fuzz, utils
import re
from re import findall 

regex_size = '([0-9]+((\.\d+)?)+(OZ|CT|oz|ct|(\sOZ)|(\sCT)|(\soz)|(\sct)))'
regex_size_oz_check = '(?=(OZ|oz|(\sOZ)|(\soz)))'
regex_size_ct_check = '(?=(CT|ct|(\sCT)|(\sct)))'

with open('IC_ITM_CROSS_REF', 'r') as hosts:
   reader = csv.reader(hosts, delimiter='|')

   choice_mappings = {choice: utils.default_process(choice) for choice in  all_other_item_desc}

   #iterate through each
   for row in reader:
      #row[2] = size, can be in OZ or CT
      list1_item_desc = row[1] + " " + row[2] + " " + row[4]

      #look for matching REPORT_UPC_CODE
      if row[7] in UPC:
         message = "UPC match" 

      #if items UPC doesn't match, check if item descriptions match or not
      else:
         match = process.extractOne(
            utils.default_process(list1_item_desc),
            choice_mappings,
            processor=None,
            scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio,
            score_cutoff=80)
         if match:
            other_item_size = {x[0].replace(" ", "").lower() for x in findall(regex_size, match[2])}
            if(row[2].replace(" ", "").lower() in other_item_size) or not other_item_size:
               print("MATCH")
```